# Array to String type conversion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having trouble with passing a MYSQL associative array into a PHP array - I get the error message:

> Array to String type conversion

Here's my code:

```
$sql="SELECT brand_id FROM brand
WHERE (name IS NOT NULL OR name != '')
  AND (name != 'Hot Brands')
ORDER BY name ASC";

$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
while( $brand = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $brand; // Inside while loop
    }

    $arrlength=count($new_array);
    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {

?>

<?php

$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total
    from shop_orders
        WHERE   
    DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-05-01' AND brand = '".$new_array[$x]."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'";
} 
?>
```

Here's the result of print_r on the array

```
Array ( [brand_id] => 179 ) 
Array ( [brand_id] => 42 ) 
Array ( [brand_id] => 174 ) 
Array ( [brand_id] => 37 ) 
Array ( [brand_id] => 26 ) 
Array ( [brand_id] => 223 ) ... etc
```

Could somebody please explain why it isn't passing the `brand_id` integer into the `SELECT COUNT(*)` Statement?

Thanks.

Comment: the output of mysql_fetch_assoc is an array.. you need to specify the index which is the name of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing to `$new_array` an array with `brand_id` key and ID value. You want to push just the integer value, so just try with:

```
while ($brand = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $new_array[] = (int) $brand['brand_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define $new_array array before while loop and also brand_id as key as below:

```
$sql="SELECT brand_id FROM brand
WHERE (name IS NOT NULL OR name != '')
  AND (name != 'Hot Brands')
ORDER BY name ASC";

$new_array = array();

$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
while( $brand = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $brand; // Inside while loop
    }

    $arrlength=count($new_array);
    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {

?>

<?php

$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total
    from shop_orders
        WHERE   
    DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-05-01' AND brand = '".$new_array[$x]['brand_id']."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'";
} 
?>
```

So you don't use

```
$new_array[$x]
```

but

```
$new_array[$x]['brand_id']
```

Of course in such simple case you could also add to array just brand_id value as in previous answer.

You should also not use mysql functions but mysqli